# Has the scope of the site changed?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope, close-reasons

I noticed that [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/45601/9718) (about shortening existing solutions to the Rubik's cube) was downvoted and migrated off the site.  To me it seems like an on-topic question.  After all, the [help center](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says:

> If you have a question about [...] A specific method of solving a type of puzzle [...] then this site is the right place for you!

And the sidebar when asking a new question asks (emphasis mine):

> Is your question about creation and **solving** of puzzles?

---

However, a highly-upvoted comment on the question read (Not the exact wording, I can no longer get to the original question.):

> I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is not a puzzle.

This would lead me to believe that the community has decided that questions *about puzzles* are not on topic, only *actual puzzles* are.

---

### Question

Has the scope of the site changed to exclude questions about puzzles?  Should we update the help center &c. to reflect this?

Comment: This reminds me of some misunderstandings on this question: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42288/is-there-some-oil-grease-or-substance-i-can-find-at-home-or-in-the-garage-or-o#comment125985_42288

Comment: (1) Another recent example that was accused of being off-topic is [Constructing interesting “Don’t Know – Don’t Know – Now I know!” type puzzles](//puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/35231/19765).  (It was deemed to be on-topic, and received several good answers.) (2) You got the comment almost right: it was “I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isnt a puzzle” [sic] You can see the original question at http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45601?noredirect=1.  Interestingly, the comment was by the same user who made the first off-topic comment on the “Don’t Know” question.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No. I don't think the site's scope has changed, and I disagree with the closing of that question - *especially* the reason behind the closing. Questions about puzzles are still perfectly acceptable here. I think this problem was simply a misguided user voting to close, and other people following suit.

Comment: ... and a misguided moderator migrating it? (Migrations require a moderator, except between a single site and its meta.)

Comment: I also firmly believe these questions are categorically on-topic and appropriate for the site, and I'm sorry to see it was downvoted this heavily.

Comment: I migrated the question not because it was not a puzzle, but it seemed to be a question specifically about modifying an algorithm, which to me seemed more appropriate for [cs.se].  I'm am quite open to being told I'm wrong and that it should remain.  I *definitely* agree that non-puzzle questions *about* puzzles are *on-topic* and should remain.

Comment: Triple Diamonds.

Comment: @Lordofdark ♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦

Answer (score 3):

This specific question, both on first blush and even now on a more careful re-reading, appears to be not merely about solving a puzzle — nor even solving it optimally — but about programmatically assembling different cube solving methods (or, equivalently, their move sequences) to create a solution sequence for an arbitrary 3x3 cube, and then programmatically transforming that into an equivalent but now optimal sequence.  I am still not fully convinced that it isn't.

If the question had been, say, **what is the optimal algorithm for solving a 3x3 Rubik's Cube, i.e. not one designed around ease of use or practicality of remembering but rather purely focused on fewest steps to completion**, then there would be no question in my mind it would be appropriate here. But that doesn't seem to me to be what the questioner asked or wanted.

Comment: I think you're exactly right.  But I think that questions about specific methods of solving puzzles (or in this case, specific methods of improving solutions to puzzles) are still on-topic under the old rules.